# How to forward all media group in whole with python telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I used `sendMediaGroup` to send a media group to a channel with my bot.
Now I'm going to need to forward all that media group to a specific chat id in whole (with one message not more).

but a media group when sent is actually a list of media which is requested to url:

[https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot-token}/sendMediaGroup](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Bbot-token%7D/sendMediaGroup)

which is not treated as ONE message with ONE message id. And in the other hand `forward_message` gets a message id from a specific chat and forwards it to the target. so When we want to forward the messages returned from the url, .../sendMediaGroup, we are actually splitting a media groups into its media and forwarding them one by one.

So how can we forward that one message which is the whole media group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media groups are indeed just a bunch of messages that are nicely displayed by the client and as of Bot API 5.2 there is no method to forward them as a whole. However, since you're sending the media group to the channel yourself, you could just send it to the chat via `sendMediaGroup`, too, instead of of forwarding.

Comment: I know I could send it directly to the chat I wanted in the first place, but I needed my channel name be on the top of my message.

Comment: Your answer was useful though. I didn't know telegram bot api does not support this feature up to now. Thank you so much

Comment: no problem. You could just add your channel name as caption, though …